# How to change kernel version in ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I have already installed

1. 4.15.0-112-generic
2. 5.3.0-1023-aws
3. 5.3.0-1030-aws

But when I execute `uname -r` that time shows only this one 5.3.0-1023-aws
I want to change 4.15.0-112-generic instead of this 5.3.0-1023-aws
Because this command is not executed in my ubuntu
[image]

Please fast to solve this problem give me a proper guideline of this

Answer (score 1):

1. grep gnulinux /boot/grub/grub.cfg
2. choose and add line to /etc/default/grub -> GRUB_DEFAULT=
3. update-grub and reboot